# Define array to use in all udf

Tags: vba

I'm writing a UDF in which I'm using an aray that is filled from another workbook. 
It works, but, it's rather slow.

I'm thinking that's because every instance of the UDF (20000+ lines) calls to the other workbook to fill the array.

Below is the function. What I'm asking is: can the sourceCategorie be filled by a sub globally, so nog every line has to call on the other workbook. Could this improve performance?

```
public Function categorieoppunten(punten As Double) As Integer

Dim sourceCategorie As Variant
Dim categorie, i As Integer

sourceCategorie = Workbooks("Brontabellen.xlsx").Worksheets("Bron").range("C46:C68").Value
For i = 23 To 1 Step -1
    If punten < sourceCategorie(i, 1) Then
    categorie = i
    End If
Next i


categorieoppunten = categorie
End Function
```

Comment: For sure, make the array global and populate it on the first call by checking if it's empty. If it's empty - populate it, if it's not - then just use it

Comment: If you use a Global or Static variable then make sure there's a mechanism to re-read the contents in the event that's required.  Updating the source range will not auto-update the array.

Comment: If you think the other workbook will change, then save the timestamp of the workbook when you update your array. Then you can check that timestamp against the current timestamp of the workbook file. If the file has a more recent timestamp, you may assume the array needs updating.

Comment: Though keep in mind that the worksheet may have been updated without the file having been saved.